# Get parent node in Tree cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, php-5.6, cakephp-3.6

let's say that I have a table called **categories** which is using the Tree Behavior in a CakePHP 3 application. If I'm given a Category id, are there functions that allow me to check if the Category is a parent Category or fuctions to get the parent Category of a node without having to do multiple find queries?

I couldn't find anything on the web.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

TreeBehavior use `parent_id` field, so You can prepare relations named `ParentCategories` and `ChildrenCategories`.

```
$this->belongsTo('ParentCategories', [
    'className' => 'Categories',
    'foreignKey' => 'parent_id',
]);

$this->hasMany('ChildrenCategories', [
    'className' => 'Categories',
    'foreignKey' => 'parent_id',
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Cakephp 3](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/tree.html)

there is already a **Path** finder available to find the complete path for a specific node/id.
Using this you can get the parent node as below:

```
$completePath = $this->Model->find('path', ['for' => $category_id])->first();
$parentNode = $completePath['id'];
```

Further reference: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/12539

Hope this will help!

Comment: this will ffind the first parent, not the last one